# dotenv is not giving values properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

Am confused here. Someone, please help me,
Have a string written in .env file, given below,

```
AUTH_CREDENTIALS={"username":"Auth_user1","password":"ABC123"}/{"username":"Auth_user2","password":"ABC-1"}
```

Am reading it as

```
var config = process.env.AUTH_CREDENTIALS.split('/');
```

lets say, after reading, am running it in a for-in loop and parsing the config files, object at each index,
And the below happens,

When I start the process and console this config variable, I get different results,
the first one is

```
[ '{"username":"Auth_user1","password":"ABC123"}',
  '{"username":"Auth_user2","password":"ABC-1"}' ]
```

which is correct for my purpose, but for the second time, if I am hitting this API and seeing the result, I get

```
[ { username: 'Auth_user1', password: 'ABC123' },
  { username: 'Auth_user2', password: 'ABC-1' } ]
```

The quotes get replaced

Note: It works for the first time well when I start the process. It doesn't work for the consecutive calls with the process running. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to store in an array in your '.env' and you would directly retrieve an array, not needing to split and your quotes should remain.

`AUTH_CREDENTIALS=[{"username":"Auth_user1","password":"ABC123"},{"username":"Auth_user2","password":"ABC-1"}]`

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot. Did the same way.